# C loop conversion for multiple hexadecimal values

Tags: arrays, c, loops

I´m new to C and I would like to convert hexadecimal numbers to decimal numbers.
I have three numbers as input and each of them should be used later on for different calculations. The conversion works so far, but I don´t know how I can repeat this for every input. So for example the user enter: a, b, c. Output would be a = 1, b = 2, c = 3

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#define ARRAY_SIZE  20
int main()
{
    char hex[ARRAY_SIZE];
    long long decimal = 0, base = 1;
    int i = 0, value, length;
    /* Get hexadecimal value from user */
    printf("Enter hexadecimal message: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(hex,ARRAY_SIZE,stdin);
    length = strlen(hex);
    for(i = length--; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if(hex[i] >= '0' && hex[i] <= '9')
        {
            decimal += (hex[i] - 48) * base;
            base *= 16;
        }
        else if(hex[i] >= 'A' && hex[i] <= 'F')
        {
            decimal += (hex[i] - 55) * base;
            base *= 16;
        }
        else if(hex[i] >= 'a' && hex[i] <= 'f')
        {
            decimal += (hex[i] - 87) * base;
            base *= 16;
        }
    }
    printf("\nHexadecimal number = %s", hex);
    printf("Decimal number = %lld\n", decimal);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can move the code which converts hex to decimal to a function and call it 3 times using a loop.
[refer](https://onlinegdb.com/4jZsUmZU1)

Comment: Instead of using your own function, you might as well use `strtol` with `16` as the third argument.

Comment: great thanks @TruthSeeker! That´s what I was looking for. Now I would like to declare each return decimal output from the function different, so that I can use these later on. Is there any possibility to do that?

Comment: you need not to have 3 functions, indeed you can have single function called multiple times. If you notice the code, function is being called 3times inside the `for-loop` 3 times.

Comment: yes, I understand that. Maybe I descriped this incorrectly. I call the function three times in the loop and for every time I would like to get the return and use it for other calculations in the main. So for expamle: forloop 1:  message = return decimal; forloop 2: expo = return decimal ; foorloop 3: modulo = retrun decimal; then message*expo %modulo = result. I know there are three ways to do it: arrays, pointer and structure. But I really don´t knwo how to implement them in the hex function

Comment: Function can return a value for every string passed and you can make use of return value of the function.

Comment: Thank you, I got it!